# iOS: Which way do I go for when dealing with network communication in background

Tags: ios, networking, download, background, upload

I am having difficulty which scenario to be used on iOS dealing with network communication in the background.

My scenario is to have a background code to be executed even the application was suspended on a particular period eg. when the network become available. User use the application in an offline mode and saved them in local storage. When the user back online, the app knows and start upload/download new contents while the app in background or not even running.

I am loading on the background transfer service, I think that isn't the right route for me, it only dealing with downloading for each file. I also looking at the Background Fetch Mode, this only download content from remote not uploading.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I did't think we can achieve this  "When the user back online, the app knows and start upload/download new contents while the app in background or not even running."  ... maybe silent notifications will work from updating the content

Comment: You can use "background fetch" mode to periodically be woken and upload data if you have any

Comment: Is that apply to upload as well